# Login with QRCode in Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, identity

I have the identity server 4(skurba) I want to login a user with QrCode like whatsapp application. In the other words the user is login in web application  and want to scan Qrcode by their phone to login with mobile app. I want the standard scenario in OIDC and with identity server 4 . Somebody  suggests the device flow but in device flow user must input credential like user and password .

I create the API to save device code in DeviceCodes table(default table in identity server 4 and skurba) and I send it (device code) to token endpoint. I got the invalid grant response. After that I send this request to deviceauthorization endpoint :

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:44310/connect/deviceauthorization' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=Mahdi' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid'
```

and the response was:

```
{
    "device_code": "A3B6F0F20089F3135368E91083588C2750C3396E4D529ACCBFBD9D8DA4EE806D",
    "user_code": "337168620",
    "verification_uri": "http://localhost:44310/device",
    "verification_uri_complete": "http://localhost:44310/device?userCode=337168620",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "interval": 5
}
```

so I send the device code to token endpoint :

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:44310/connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=Mahdi' \
--data-urlencode 'device_code=A3B6F0F20089F3135368E91083588C2750C3396E4D529ACCBFBD9D8DA4EE806D'
```

and I got this response:

```
{
    "error": "authorization_pending"
}
```

Another problem is that I want to get a token for a specific user in this scenario user is not specific.

Comment: so long story short you want to skip the device authorization correct ? btw that is the reason of the authorization pending error.

Comment: https://www.identityserver.com/articles/an-introduction-to-the-oauth-device-flow

Answer (score 0):

You received the error below because it's missing the device authorization part.

> {
> "error": "authorization_pending"
> }

Basically, you want to skip the device authorization, to achieve that you have 2 options:

- You can change the native behavior of your IdentityServer4 where in the device flow (GrantTypes.DeviceCode) you disable the RequireUserConsent by setting it as false. I strongly do **NOT** recommend proceeding with this option since this approach has some vulnerability risks.
- You can create a new custom API for device authorization where you create a new user or link an existing user to the device, which will allow you to use the device code on /connect/token and get your access token and refresh token (if your client has offline_access set). Follow one example below:

  ```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [HttpPost("device/authorization")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> DeviceAuthorizationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       //Here you can create a new user or use an existing one like I'm doing below
       var identityServerUser = new IdentityServerUser("25389eb0-b27a-4d96-bbf8-faaaa98356e8")// Existing UserId
       {
           IdentityProvider = "local",
           AuthenticationTime = DateTime.UtcNow
       };

       var deviceCode = new DeviceCode
       {
           ClientId = "my-client-id",
           IsAuthorized = true,
           Subject = identityServerUser.CreatePrincipal(),
           IsOpenId = true,
           Lifetime = 300,
           CreationTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
           AuthorizedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "offline_access" }
       };

       var handle = await _deviceFlowCodeService.StoreDeviceAuthorizationAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), deviceCode);

       return Ok(handle); //Returning the DeviceCode to be used inside /connect/token
   }
  ```

And then you can use the device code from the response in your /connect/token

> curl --location 'http://localhost:5127/connect/token' 
> --header 'Authorization: Basic > a5wbF5dGlc2RdmljZTp7OTQ0Q3NztMkE11BRTk3LTQyNjYtQUM0RTFFQTkxjczfQ==' 
> --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
> --data-urlencode > 'device_code=E9FADB639D07081DBDC08F991B13971D06A79D289AAC1CBE54BFB20FB60F458F' 
> --data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code'